# access civimail images from Drupal media browser

Tags: drupal, civimail, images

If we wish to reuse images in a node on the main Drupal site uploaded for a CiviMail email newsletter, we can not access with the media browser widget for a field from: sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/image

Is there a way to change this? (More of a Drupal question than a CiviCRM question.)
Currently everything has to be uploaded twice if first used in CiviMail.

Answer (score 0):

possibly the same answer per your other Question, namely upgrade to 7.7.1